# Generating SAS URL for Azure Data Lake Storage

Tags: python, azure-data-lake

I would like to reach my files which located under Data lake storage folder filesystem from my computer using python. I have generated sas token and created sas url with this piece of code

```
sas_file = generate_file_sas(account_name=account_name,
                  file_system_name = file_system_name ,
                  directory_name = directory_name ,
                  file_name = file_name,
                  credential=account_key,
                  expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
                  )
sas_url = 'https://' + account_name+'.blob.core.windows.net/' + container_name + '/' + directory_name + '/' + file_name + '?'+  sas_file
```

but i can't download any file from this script. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one file named **`logo.jpg`** in directory of my Data lake storage folder filesystem like this:

[image]

I used below python code to generate **SAS URL** and download file to local folder like this:

```py
from azure.storage.filedatalake import generate_file_system_sas,FileSystemSasPermissions
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import requests

account_name="deviadlsgen2acc"
file_system_name="sri"
directory_name="dir1"
account_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
file_name="logo.jpg"
file_path="C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Documents\\folder1\\test.jpg"

sas_token = generate_file_system_sas(
    account_name=account_name,
    file_system_name=file_system_name,
    credential=account_key,
    permission=FileSystemSasPermissions(read=True),
    expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
)
sas_url = 'https://' + account_name+'.dfs.core.windows.net/' + file_system_name + '/' + directory_name + '/' + file_name + '?'+  sas_token
print(sas_url)   

response = requests.get(sas_url)
with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
     f.write(response.content)
     print("File downloaded successfully!!!!)
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked that file path, file **downloaded** successfully to local folder like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[azure.storage.filedatalake package | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-datalake/azure.storage.filedatalake?view=azure-python)

Comment: It was the exact solution that I am looking for, thanks a lot :)